# spaCy named entity recognition does not seem to work if the entity was at the beginning of the string

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm using spaCy named entity recognition (NER) to parse names out of English sentences and I've noticed that if the named entity was at the very beginning of the sentence, it won't be picked up. let me show you an example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

s = 'It must have made sense to Dumbledore, though, because he put it back in his pocket and said, Hagrid’s late.'

doc = nlp(s)

named_entities = [] 
if doc.ents:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        named_entities.append((ent.text, ent.label_))

for name in named_entities:
    print(name)
```

this works as expected and gives the output

```
('Dumbledore', 'PERSON')
('Hagrid', 'ORG')
```

however, if I were to use the following sentence

```
s = "Dumbledore, however, was choosing another lemon drop and did not answer."
```

or any other sentence that starts with "Dumbledore", the code above will not pick up Dumbledore as a person.

any suggestions on what could be the problem here

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue as well. It is really weird. When I add just any token (e.g., 'hey') at the beginning of the second example, Dumbledore is marked as a person, although neither the pos tag (propn) nor the dep tag (nsubj) change.